# Binding TimeSpan to a DataGridView column

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, timespan

Is there an easy way to show a formatted string representing a `TimeSpan` field in a `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` of a `DataGridView`?

I have an array of custom objects (returned by a web service) that I'm binding to my datagrid. These object have a `TimeSpan` property. When I bind this property to the column of the datagrid I obtain the object name (something like *MyApplication.MyClass.TimeSpan*) and not the timespan string.

How can I solve?

**NOTE:**
At last I discovered my problem is that I get my array of objects **from a web service**.
It seems that `TimeSpan` type cannot be xml-serialized, so the system class is *re-classed* into a custom object:

- https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/94492/timestamp-class-should-be-xml-serializable
- http://forums.silverlight.net/t/51793.aspx

Comment: Have you googled how to use time span.. are you binding that to a property or variable for example var tick =  (TimeSpan)( endTick - startTick); ???

Comment: @DJKRAZE I have an array of custom objects that I'm binding to my datagrid. These object have a `TimeSpan` property. When I bind this property to the column of the datagrid I obtain the object name and not the timespan string.

Comment: Did you create your own `TimeSpan` class nested in `MyClass`?  The string `"MyApplication.MyClass.TimeSpan"` looks like the return value of `object.ToString()` for an instance of a class that hasn't overridden the method.  In that case, you just get the type name.

Comment: I don't think that you mentioned that in your initial Description but looks like you have a viable answer.. happy Friday..

Comment: @phoog My custom object is returned by a web service... I didn't create my own TimeSpan object, could it be the cause of the different ToString behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a read-only string property in your object that will represent the formatted TimeSpan. Something like:

```
public class MyObject
{
private TimeSpan _myTimeSpan;

// ...

public string TimeSpanFormatted
{
    get
    {
         return _myTimeSpan.ToString("c");
    }
}

// ...
}
```

Then add a column for this property and hide the "raw" TimeSpan column.

See [here for TimeSpan formatting info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286.aspx).

**NOTE:** For your column's properties be sure to set the DataMember to TimeSpanFormatted

Comment: so I need to add another property to my object...?

Answer (score 1):

This displayed a value for me:

```
class TimeSpanItem
{
    public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
}
```

and use this:

```
DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
// 
// dataGridView1
// 
dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new DataGridViewColumn[] {
Column1});
dataGridView1.Location = new Point(38, 58);
dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
dataGridView1.Size = new Size(240, 150);
dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0;
// 
// Column1
// 
Column1.HeaderText = "Column1";
Column1.Name = "Column1";
Column1.DataPropertyName = "Time";
this.Controls.Add(dataGridView1);
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(dataGridView1)).EndInit();

List<TimeSpanItem> list = new List<TimeSpanItem>();
list.Add(new TimeSpanItem() { Time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay });

dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
```

[image]